# Why does my Paloma tankless water heater turn off randomly without errors?

Tags: water-heater

We have a Paloma Tankless water heater, model: PTG-74PVN that shuts down when in use for a few minutes. There is no code displayed on the screen, it just powers down. This started happening a few weeks ago after 5 or 10 minutes, but now it happens after around 1 or 2 minutes, making for some brisk showers. In the past when we've had issues, there's always been an error code displayed that has helped when troubleshooting.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After calling Paloma, they suggested disconnecting the thermostat. I noticed that the filter was dirty and cleaned it as well. So far it seems to be working again. If I don't have problems in a week, I'll try reconnecting the thermostat and see if the problem was just the dirty filter.

Comment: It was just the filter, but the latest failure was due to some blown capacitors on the system board.

Comment: I had another failure that had an error code that required disassembly and cleaning.